# i can't get POST data when i use express

Tags: javascript, node.js

Here are my codes:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/:name', function(req,res){
    res.setHeader('Content-Type','text/html');
    res.send('<form action="/" method="POST"><input type="text" name="self"/><input type="submit"/></form>');
});

app.post('/',function(req,res){
    res.send(req.body.self);
});

app.listen(8080);
```

I call localhost:8080/examplename

and write something inside of input, and I click submit button. It goes to localhost:8080 but node returns error as below:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'self' of undefined
    at /home/yusuf/MasaÃ¼stÃ¼/node/ue.js:10:19
    at callbacks (/home/yusuf/MasaÃ¼stÃ¼/node/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:160:37)
    at param (/home/yusuf/MasaÃ¼stÃ¼/node/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:134:11)
    at pass (/home/yusuf/MasaÃ¼stÃ¼/node/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:141:5)
    at Router._dispatch (/home/yusuf/MasaÃ¼stÃ¼/node/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:169:4)
    at Object.router [as handle] (/home/yusuf/MasaÃ¼stÃ¼/node/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:32:10)
    at next (/home/yusuf/MasaÃ¼stÃ¼/node/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:190:15)
    at Object.expressInit [as handle] (/home/yusuf/MasaÃ¼stÃ¼/node/node_modules/express/lib/middleware.js:31:5)
    at next (/home/yusuf/MasaÃ¼stÃ¼/node/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:190:15)
    at Object.query [as handle] (/home/yusuf/MasaÃ¼stÃ¼/node/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/query.js:44:5)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to enable the body parser middleware. Insert this before you configure your routes.

```
app.use(express.bodyParser());
```

You can also configure other things here, such as the view engine, static directory, etc. For example,

```
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'swig');
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

Answer (score 1):

req.body allows you to get the data sent in POST. You can then use req.body.[name of data] to actually access data. For example, if you sent a "firstname":

```
req.body.firstname
```

You can also use res.render to send data to your template page. For example, this sends the firstname to your index page rendered by your templating language.

```
res.render('index', {fname: req.body.firstname});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the bodyParser. Here is your exact code, with the parser added, and working as expected:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

// parses POST bodies:
app.use(express.bodyParser());

app.get('/:name', function(req,res){
    res.setHeader('Content-Type','text/html');
    res.send('<form action="/" method="POST"><input type="text" name="self"/><input type="submit"/></form>');
});

app.post('/',function(req, res){
  res.send(req.body.self);
});

app.listen(8080);
```